# Tika parsing gives maximum limit reached error

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika for getting content from PDF files.
 When I run it I get below error. I don't see this error documented anywhere and this is just a bad surprise.

```
org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler$WriteLimitReachedException: Your document contained more than 100000 characters, and so your requested limit has been reached. To receive the full text of the document, increase your limit. (Text up to the limit is however available).
    at org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler.characters(WriteOutContentHandler.java:141)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.MatchingContentHandler.characters(MatchingContentHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.characters(SecureContentHandler.java:270)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.access$001(SafeContentHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler$1.write(SafeContentHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.filter(SafeContentHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.characters(SafeContentHandler.java:287)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.characters(XHTMLContentHandler.java:279)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.characters(XHTMLContentHandler.java:306)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.writeWordSeparator(PDF2XHTML.java:318)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeLine(PDFTextStripper.java:1741)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writePage(PDFTextStripper.java:672)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:392)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:141)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:111)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:136)
```

Just want to know how to get away with this error and be able to parse files again. Or How to make this limit unlimited.

Comment: Why not do what the error message tells you to do, and increase (or even remove!) the character limit?

Comment: And how and where to do that? I dont see that anywhere in Apache doc... If u know can you be kind enough to enlighten me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `writeLimit` to set the limit or even disable it using:

```
public BodyContentHandler(int writeLimit)
```

The [docs](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html#BodyContentHandler%28int%29) says the following:

> writeLimit - maximum number of characters to include in the string, or
>   -1 to disable the write limit